# How to disable a node in node editor?

Tags: node-editor, shortcut

I have a texture node, I want to keep as it is and try another texture creating another texture node. I don't want to use the same texture node to try both.

How can disable node in node editor temporarily? In Nuke, it used to be <kbd>d</kbd> (for *disable*). Pressing <kbd>d</kbd>, of course, does not work in Blender. My intuition says there might be similar in Blender.

[image: Disable option in Nuke DAG with 'd' key]

Answer (score 3):

The concept of <kbd>d</kbd>isabling in Blender is known as *Muting*. The shortcut is <kbd>m</kbd>.

You can also right-click on a node (unlike Nuke) to pop up ***Node Context Menu***.

[image: Node Context Menu]